# Power BI DAX: date slicer filter does not affect custom measure that uses CALCULATE

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am struggling to understand the behavior of the filter slicers and custom measures when using the `CALCULATE` DAX formula. My goal is pretty simple: I have a sales table that includes both the sales date and the ship date (see the below screenshot), and I have created two custom measures:

```
Sold products = CALCULATE(
    COUNT('dummy data'[SaleID])
)
```

```
Shipped products = CALCULATE(
    COUNT('dummy data'[SaleID]),
    NOT(ISBLANK('dummy data'[Ship date]))
)
```

*Note that the table will always have a sale date but may not have a shipping date (yet), also shipping date will always be a "past date".*

I have added a filter slicer in the canvas using the `'dummy data'[Ship date]` column (note that is the same field I am using on my `Shipped products` measure).

When I attempt to use the date filter slicer (e.g., shipped products between two specific dates), the `Shipped products` measure does not change based on the filters applied.

Why does this happen? I would appreciate any extensive explanation that may help me understand the behavior of this scenario and, ideally, a solution of how I can make this work, how I can use the filter slicer for the `Ship Date` at the same time it is being used as part of the `CALCULATE` filter condition.

---

**Table:**

[image]

**Canvas report without filter slicer**

[image]

**Canvas report with specific date range applied on filter slicer:**

[image]

**Expected result: `Shipped products` should be 7**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the filter context in your measure.

CALCULATE() is used to overwrite the filter context and the part that says:

```
NOT(ISBLANK('dummy data'[Ship date]))
```

is overwriting that context. Also, for it to respond to slicers, you'll need to use ALLSELECTED() at some point.

You should really be using a date table too.

In your specific case, a simple measure like this will work and respond to slicers.

```
Shipped products = COUNT('dummy data'[SaleID])
```

I suggest you read more about CALCULATE() here:

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/introducing-calculate-in-dax/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. How would `Shipped products = COUNT('dummy data'[SaleID])` produce a different result than "Sold products" in your example? Considering that they are looking at different "dates". Thanks for clarifying the fact that I am overwriting the context with the CALCULATE function.